# Error starting penguin container: 15 Launching vmshell failed: Error starting crostini for terminal: 15|| What to do?

Tags: sudo, virtual-console

So I tried to download steam but it went wrong so I tried to uninstall it. It then said that there was an error and that I should try uninstalling it through the terminal. I didn't know how to uninstall apps like that so I put 'sudo apt uninstall steam'. Then it said this 'sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database'. I thought t was because I had put it wrong so I tried the most basic command I knew, 'sudo apt update'. Once again, it said this 'sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database'. I don't know what to do. Then psomehow it started working again. But then the terminal wouldnt respond saying 'Error starting penguin container: 15
Launching vmshell failed: Error starting crostini for terminal: 15' I have o idea what to do.

Comment: Is this your computer, or one given to you by a school or company or such?  `sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database` indicates *your user* you use on the computer is NOT authorized to use the sudo command and do admin tasks.

Comment: Hmm... I thought the default message for non-authorized users was `<user> is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.` I wonder if there is something more subtle going on here (maybe with PAM)?

Comment: This is my own personal device. I used to be able to use the sudo commands as I wished.

Comment: Is your username still in the sudo group? fgrep sudo /etc/group   Any recent useranme changes or UUID changes?

Comment: Yes my username is still there.